# How to make changes in barebox code reflect in build?

Tags: linux, embedded, boot-loader, yocto

Issue: To reduce the autoboot_timeout parameter in bootloader source code.

Rugged Board---> phyBoard-Segin i.MX6UL/ULL

Current booting time is around 14 seconds and with the autoboot timeout, an extra 3 seconds. Have to reduce the timeout to 1.

**Method 1:**

@Bootloader:

cd /env/nv

ls

> barebox@Phytec phyCORE-i.MX6 Ultra Lite SOM with NAND:/env/nv ls
> .                           ..
> allow_color                 autoboot_timeout
> bootchooser.state_prefix    bootchooser.system0.boot
> bootchooser.system1.boot    bootchooser.targets
> dev.eth0.ipaddr             dev.eth0.linux.devname
> dev.eth0.mode               dev.eth0.netmask
> dev.eth0.serverip           dhcp.vendor_id
> linux.bootargs.base         linux.bootargs.rootfs
> net.gateway                 user
> barebox@Phytec phyCORE-i.MX6 Ultra Lite SOM with NAND:/env/nv

I edit the autoboot_timeout to 1.

saveenv.

This method works, I have verified. Now I wish to make the same changes in the barebox source code and have it reflect[As per Project requirement, the same change should not be made here but rather in the source code]

Reverting all the changes made here.

**Method 2:**

> bitbake barebox -c devshell

> cd defaultenv/defaultenv-2-base/bin/

I edit the init file, change the autoboot timeout parameter to 1.

Snippet:

> root@hp15t:~/yocto/build/tmp/work/phyboard_segin_imx6ul_2-phytec-linux-gnueabi/barebox/2019.01.0-phy7-r7.0/git/defaultenv/defaultenv-2-base/bin#
> cat init
> #!/bin/sh
>
> export PATH=/env/bin
>
> global hostname global user global autoboot_timeout global
> autoboot_abort_key global boot.default global linux.bootargs.base
> global linux.bootargs.console
> #linux.bootargs.dyn.* will be cleared at the beginning of boot global linux.bootargs.dyn.ip global linux.bootargs.dyn.root global editcmd
>
> [ -z "${global.hostname}" ] && global.hostname=generic [ -z
> "${global.user}" ] && global.user=none magicvar -a global.user
> "username (used in network filenames)" [ -z
> "${global.autoboot_timeout}" ] && ***global.autoboot_timeout=1***
> magicvar -a global.autoboot_timeout "timeout in seconds before
> automatic booting" [ -z "${global.autoboot_abort_key}" ] &&
> global.autoboot_abort_key=any magicvar -a global.autoboot_abort_key
> "key to abort automatic booting (valid options: any, ctrl-c)" [ -z
> "${global.boot.default}" ] && global.boot.default=net [ -z
> "${global.editcmd}" ] && global.editcmd=sedit
>
> [ -e /env/config-board ] && /env/config-board /env/config

After saving the changes[highlighted the parameter which i have changed], i run the below commands.

> bitbake barebox -c compile --force

> bitbake barebox -c deploy

> bitbake < image name >

Here when I verify, the changes made are not reflected.

Required Scenario- timeout should be 1 and board should boot up.

Obtained Scenario- it is still taking 3s and then booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation and digging around I found out. I had forgotten to update the environment in the bootloader for the changes to reflect.

Make the above changes to the file  in the path defaultenv/defaultenv-2-base/bin/init

Save the changes.

> git status
>
> git add < respective file name in the path >
>
> git commit -m " [ insert proper message for the commit ] "
>
> git show or git status [ this is to see the whether the changes made
> are present]
>
> exit
>
> bitbake barebox -c compile --force && bitbake barebox && bitbake
> barebox -c deploy
>
> bitbake < image name >

Flash the SD Card image.

Go the following path in the yocto:

> cd /deploy/images/ [ version ]/
>
> cp barebox.bin /home/< name >/boot

**@Bootloader:**

> barebox_update -t nand barebox.bin
>
> erase /dev/nand0.barebox-environment.bb [ we need to erase the old
> environment ]
>
> saveenv
>
> reset

Now the changes made will be reflected.

We can cross check in the bootloader.

> cd /env/bin/
>
> cat init [ check the autoboot_timeout. Default was 3, it has been
> changed to 1]